# Append items from Y list to one specific list from X list Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append, list-comprehension

I have two lists `x` and `y`:

`x` list have several lists inside. For example:

```
x = [['1', 'hello', 'a'], ['3', 'hello', 'b'], ['11', 'hello', 'c'], ['2', 'hello', 'd'], ['4', 'hello', 'e'], ['22', 'hello', 'f']]
```

`y` list is a single list. The items inside are urls which contain the information from each list within *x* list.

```
y = ['odd1', 'even2', 'odd3', 'even4', 'odd11', 'even22']
```

I got the information from web scraping. So I'm trying to append one single item from `y` list to one single list from `x` list. For example, `y[0]` item should be appended to `x[0]` list, but `y[1]` item should be appended to `x[3]`.

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
output = [['1', 'hello', 'a', 'odd1'], ['3', 'hello', 'b', 'odd3'], ['11', 'hello', 'c', 'odd11'], ['2', 'hello', 'd', 'even2'], ['4', 'hello', 'e', 'even4'], ['22', 'hello', 'f', 'even22']]
```

I don't know how to code this information. First, the items from `y` list are sorted, but the lists from `x` list are not. However, they have a pettern. They start with the information from *odd* rows I scraped, and then, the information from *even* rows.

I have tried with these in order to sort `x` list in the first place:

```
1. x.sort(key=int)
2. sorted(x) | Result [['1...'], ['11...], ['2...'], ['22...'], ['3...]...]
3. x = [int(x) for x in x]
```

How ever I don´t a good result.

For the other hand, I have tried to append the items from `y` to `x` lists in this simple way:

```
for i in x:
    i.append(y[:])
```

Obviusly, all items from `y` list were appended in each list from `x`

How can I solve this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
x = [['1', 'hello', 'a'], ['3', 'hello', 'b'], ['11', 'hello', 'c'], ['2', 'hello', 'd'], ['4', 'hello', 'e'], ['22', 'hello', 'f']]
y = ['odd1', 'even2', 'odd3', 'even4', 'odd11', 'even22']
x.sort(key=lambda z: int(z[0]))
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i].append(y[i])
print(x)
```

output:

```
[['1', 'hello', 'a', 'odd1'], ['2', 'hello', 'd', 'even2'], ['3', 'hello', 'b', 'odd3'], ['4', 'hello', 'e', 'even4'], ['11', 'hello', 'c', 'odd11'], ['22', 'hello', 'f', 'even22']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. It's great, @SamuelLEMAITRE.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [['1', 'hello', 'a'],
     ['3', 'hello', 'b'],
     ['11', 'hello', 'c'],
     ['2', 'hello', 'd'],
     ['4', 'hello', 'e'],
     ['22', 'hello', 'f']]

y = ['odd1', 'even2', 'odd3', 'even4', 'odd11', 'even22']

x = sorted(x, key=lambda i: int(i[0]))
y = sorted(y, key=lambda i: int(i.replace('even', '').replace('odd', '')))

print y

result = [a + [b] for a, b in zip(x, y)]
print result #prints out [['1', 'hello', 'a', 'odd1'], ['3', 'hello', 'b', 'odd3'], ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Reorder `y` with

```
In [6]: y[::2]+y[1::2]
Out[6]: ['odd1', 'odd3', 'odd11', 'even2', 'even4', 'even22']
```

Then you can pair the reordered `y`s with `x` using `zip`:

```
x = [['1', 'hello', 'a'], ['3', 'hello', 'b'], ['11', 'hello', 'c'], 
     ['2', 'hello', 'd'], ['4', 'hello', 'e'], ['22', 'hello', 'f']]
y = ['odd1', 'even2', 'odd3', 'even4', 'odd11', 'even22']
print([xi+[yi] for xi, yi in zip(x, y[::2]+y[1::2])])
```

yields

```
[['1', 'hello', 'a', 'odd1'],
 ['3', 'hello', 'b', 'odd3'],
 ['11', 'hello', 'c', 'odd11'],
 ['2', 'hello', 'd', 'even2'],
 ['4', 'hello', 'e', 'even4'],
 ['22', 'hello', 'f', 'even22']]
```

Comment: Great solution. Simple, one line and it works great. Thanks for your support.